# PHP cant connect to PGSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, pdo

I cannot get PHP to connect to PGSQL. I am running Mavericks 10.9.4. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Figured out where default PHP w/ mac was living (`which php`)
2. `rmdir` that directory
3. `brew install php54`
4. `php -v` shows new php 5.4
5. `php -m` shows no `pdo_pgsql` module
6. `brew install php54-pdo-pgsql`
7. `php -m` show `pdo_pgsql` module
8. `php -i`shows the following info

.

```
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, odbc, sqlite, pgsql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: c85105d7c6f7d70d609bb4c000257868a40840ab $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock

PDO_ODBC

PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) => enabled
ODBC Connection Pooling => Enabled, strict matching

pdo_pgsql

PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 9.4.4
Module version => 1.0.2
Revision =>  $Id: 8e4cc97fb53f418d98b489c3e9d722e48446e676 $
```

9. Open `/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini` and add `extension=pgsql.so`, then save
10. `sudo apachectl restart`
11. Open phpinfo() page
12. PDO drivers section    only shows `mysql, sqlite`
13. `Loaded Configuration File` section shows php.ini same file w/ the pgsql extension

Also whenever I run a php command in console I see

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.43_2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pgsql.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.43_2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pgsql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.43_2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pgsql.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.43_2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pgsql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```